# machine learning to create equation on a set of data

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a set data(now only 20 pair but maybe I can produce over 500 pair), my input data is `a1 , a2 , a3 , a4 , a5 , a6 , a7` and my output is `b`, I don't have any idea about equation and what it looks like.
And I am new in machine learning, which algorithm or library or framework in python should I use to prediction the equation of these data?

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not a ML expert at all but I think there is not enough info to really be able to give you the suggestion you are asking for

Comment: This looks like a regression problem ... is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: yes I think so, but not sure

Comment: What does this topic have to do with programming or development? I think you should use another site on the Stack Exchange network for these questions. See [All Sites - Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) and maybe [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is called "regression problem". For this problems there are many approaches available. The easiest one is to start with a LinearRegression Model like described here: http://benalexkeen.com/linear-regression-in-python-using-scikit-learn/

If you think the relationship between input/output is more complex you will start with nonlinear models like
https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-first-xgboost-model-python-scikit-learn/

Answer (score 0):

There are many kinds of machine learning algorithms out there, and comprehensive libraries out there as well. The Tensorflow library is generally regarded as a good source for implementing neural networks, however with so few inputs (assuming you indeed mean inputs and not features), it will probably not have enough data to train. You will need to identify if you are trying to classify values or do regression on them (do you have a finite set of values, predicting a range of values, etc.) If you're using python you may wish to check out the scikit-learn library and perhaps do some simple linear or polynomial regression, or do something like KNN for classification. If you wish to learn more and have a more comprehensive tutorial, Kaggle has some good resources (and data science tutorials) to get you started.